# Need to pass pointer-to-pointer to a C shared lib function from Python

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries, ctypes

I have a small Python program which needs to call a function from my C shared library:

C program first:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void myprint(const char*, char**);

void myprint(const char* input, char** output)
{
printf("hello world\n");
printf("input string: %s\n",input);
*output = (char*) malloc(20);
sprintf(*output,"Life is cheap\n");
printf("output string in C program: %s\n",*output);
}
```

It is compiled to a shared library:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,testlib -o testlib.so -fPIC testlib.c
```

As you will notice the function needs a char pointer-to-pointer as it's second argument. It will fill this argument and I expect the python program which calls it to be able to print it.

I am trying to achieve this from the caller python program by passing a reference to a pointer:

```
import ctypes
mem = POINTER( c_ubyte )()
testlib = ctypes.CDLL('/home/amanral/testlib.so')
testlib.myprint("hell with the world",byref(mem))
#print mem   ===> This is where I want to print back the value filled by the C function
```

I know print mem is wrong because it just prints:

```
<__main__.LP_c_ubyte object at 0x7f6460246560>
```

Is it even possible to print back the actual string stored in the memory?
Is there a better solution?

Comment: Sorry if this is off-topic, but having memory allocated out in the C space seems leaky.  How would that memory be freed?  Do C and python allocate memory in the same way?

Comment: @billjamesdev - You are right. This is leaky as of now. Ideally I want to allocate the memory in python and pass it to the C library function. Is that possible?

Comment: @billjamesdev - See my answer below. Now the buffer memory is allocated in the Python program and the pointer-to-pointer is passed to the C function. Hope this looks better?

Answer (score 0):

The problem gets solved by doing the following changes in the python program:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

plainText_pswd = "hellWithTheWorld"
encrypted_pswd = create_string_buffer(32)

testlib = ctypes.CDLL('/home/amanral/testlib.so')
testlib.myprint(plainText_pswd, pointer(pointer(encrypted_pswd)))
print "Recvd encrypted password in python program:" + encrypted_pswd.value
```

The char pointer-to-pointer required by my C library function is achieved by using 
`pointer(pointer(encrypted_pswd))` as the argument to the C function. I am not sure if it is the correct way to use but it works alright for my requirement. I am able to print the value returned by the C function as `encrypted_pswd.value`

Any comments/suggestions are still welcome.

Comment: And yes, the C program is modified to comment out the malloc there

Comment: If you allocate the memory in Python, it is sufficient to use `char* output`. 
 Then use `encrypted_pswd` to pass the output buffer.  It's already an array and its address will be passed to the function.

Comment: My C library is a third party code which I cannot modify and it expects the output to be a string pointer to pointer. Also it expects the calling program to allocate the memory. Hence used the `pointer(pointer(encrypted_pswd))` in the python program

Comment: The third party library is doing unnecessary work and making the API more complicated then. As I showed, you don't need char** if the buffer is user allocated. You mentioned commenting out the malloc which implied you could change the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate the memory in Python you can implement more directly as the following.  Note I used Python 3 and explicitly pass byte strings.

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define API __declspec(dllexport)  // Windows-specific export

API void myprint(const char* input, char* output)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    printf("input string: %s\n",input);
    sprintf(output,"Life is cheap\n");
    printf("output string in C program: %s\n",output);
}
```

**test.py**

```
import ctypes
testlib = ctypes.CDLL('test')
mem = ctypes.create_string_buffer(32)
testlib.myprint(b'hell with the world',mem)
print(mem.value)
```

**Output**

```
hello world
input string: hell with the world
output string in C program: Life is cheap

b'Life is cheap\n'
```

If you still want to have C allocate the memory you'll have to provide a function to free it if you don't want to leak:

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define API __declspec(dllexport)  // Windows-specific export

API void myprint(const char* input, char** output)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    printf("input string: %s\n",input);
    *output = malloc(32);
    printf("output address: %p\n",*output);
    sprintf(*output,"Life is cheap\n");
    printf("output string in C program: %s\n",*output);
}

API void myfree(char* mem)
{
    printf("freeing %p\n",mem);
    free(mem);
}
```

**test.py**

```
import ctypes
testlib = ctypes.CDLL('test')

# allocate a pointer to hold the result
mem = ctypes.c_char_p()

# Pass it by reference to be modified
testlib.myprint(b'hell with the world',ctypes.byref(mem))
print(mem.value)
testlib.myfree(mem)
```

**Output**

```
hello world
input string: hell with the world
output address: 0000028CEE9BAE50
output string in C program: Life is cheap

b'Life is cheap\n'
freeing 0000028CEE9BAE50
```